# Select records 4 to 6

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm currently working with MS Access and I've got the following simple query:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM Beitrag ORDER BY Erstellungsdatum DESC;
```

This is working just fine and it gives me the Top 3 records (ordered by creation date).
Now when a function "ShowNextPage" is called, I want to get the records 4 to 6, then 7 to 9 and so on. 
How would the Sql query look like?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM 
(
SELECT TOP 6 * FROM Beitrag ORDER BY Erstellungsdatum DESC
)
```

Comment: That's clever but wouldn't it be 'ASC' in that case? Thanks though I think I've got the input i needed :)

Comment: `SELECT TOP 3 * FROM Beitrag WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT TOP 3 Id FROM Beitrag ORDER BY Erstellungsdatum DESC) ORDER BY Erstellungsdatum DESC;` <- Finally it worked like this

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
 SELECT TOP 6 * 
 FROM Beitrag 
 ORDER BY Erstellungsdatum DESC
     MINUS
 SELECT TOP 3 * 
 FROM Beitrag 
 ORDER BY Erstellungsdatum DESC;
```

hope this can help you.